# Biztalk flat file schema tag identifier support regexp or not

Tags: biztalk

We have a flat file with content is like below:

> aaa bbb ccc
>   < xxx yyy zzz

We want to specify both ">" and "<" as the tag identifier, but unfortunately, seems Biztalk flat file schema does not support regexp such that only either ">" or "<" can be specified as tag identifier.

Is my understanding wrong? Is Biztalk flat file schema tag identifier support regexp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, no, the Tag property takes a single string only.